# How can i select total sum of 2 values and show

Tags: php, mysql

i want to do is select total sum  of (Money+Bank-Money) and show top 10 list of (Money+Bank-Money) = total-balance  from players table

that's the query i use to get data but that doesn't work

```
SELECT `id`,`Username`, SUM(`Money`+`Bank-money`) 
AS total-balance 
FROM `players` 
ORDER BY total-balance DESC LIMIT 0,10"
```

how can i do it ?

thanks

Comment: How does it not work exactly?

Comment: it shows only one guy from that table

Comment: You probably don't need `SUM` just `(Money+Bank-money) as total-balance` (properly escaped). Assuming you want to show the top 10 richest players

Comment: Show your results too

Answer (score 4):

`SUM()` is for adding values from different rows. If you want the sum of different columns within a row, just add them:

```
SELECT `id`,`Username`, `Money` + `Bank-money` AS total-balance 
FROM `players` 
ORDER BY total-balance DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: This answer is probably what he is looking for based on his attempt and Q.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `GROUP BY` and`COALESCE` (to handle NULL values):

```
SELECT `Username`,
       SUM(COALESCE(`Money`,0)+COALESCE(`Bank-money`,0)) AS `total-balance` 
FROM `players` 
GROUP BY `Username`
ORDER BY `total-balance` DESC 
LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: Given he wants ID and Username... this query looks like overkill as it would not really 'group' anything since ID is hopefully unique. But its a good example of group by for totals!